# Can I use the same flow.xml.gz for two different Nifi cluster?

Tags: apache-nifi, cloudera

We have a 13 nodes nifi cluster with around 50k processors. The size of the flow.xml.gz is around 300MB. To bring up the 13 nodes Nifi cluster, it usually takes 8-10 hours. Recently we split the cluster into two parts, 5nodes cluster and 8 nodes cluster with the same 300MB flow.xml.gz in both. Since then we are not able to get the Nifi up in both the clusters. Also we are not seeing any valid logs related to this issue. Is it okay to have the same flow.xml.gz . What are the best practices we could be missing here when splitting the Nifi Cluster.

Comment: How did you split the cluster exactly? Are they still sharing the zookeeper cluster?

Comment: @Cyrus Yes we are still using the same Zookeeper for both the nifi clusters. Is there any problem with that.

Comment: There shouldn't be, if you have specified a different root node instead of /nifi. If both clusters are still trying to write to the /nifi root node it won't work.

Comment: @Cyrus We separated root node. Both the clusters are having different root nodes in zookeeper.  Cluster-1 is configured with /nifi1 and cluster-2 is configured with /nifi2.

Comment: I don't have any experience with a flow of that immense size, but since each node loads and runs the full flow, there should be no reason a smaller cluster couldn't run it. Have you tried loading the flow on a standalone NiFi installation?

Comment: @Cyrus We don't have a standalone Nifi. But we had started only one node in the cluster and allowed it to run. The node got connected in 1st attempt itself.  And when we started  all other nodes in the cluster, then those nodes were in  connecting state for some time and then got disconnected.   Moreover earlier with Single 13 nodes Nifi cluster all nodes were connected and working fine, but only problem was 13 nodes cluster was too slow and going down frequently.

Comment: There must be some WARN or ERROR messages around the time of disconnection. To be honest, even with those I don't know if I can answer your questions, but I will at least try to give some pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask a number of questions that all boil down to "How to improve performance of our NiFi cluster with a very large flow.xml.gz".
Without a lot more details on your cluster and the flows in it, I can't give a definite or guaranteed-to-work answer, but I can point out some of the steps.

**Splitting the cluster is no good without splitting the flow.**

Yes, you will reduce cluster communications overhead somewhat, but you probably have a number of input processors that are set to "Primary Node only". If you load the same flow.xml.gz on two clusters, both will have a primary node executing these, leading to contention issues.

More importantly, since every node still loads all of the flow.xml.gz (probably 4 Gb unzipped), you don't have any other performance benefits and verifying the 50k processors in the flow at startup still takes ages.

**How to split the cluster**

Splitting the cluster in the way you did probably left references to nodes that are now in the other cluster, for example in the local state directory. For NiFi clustering, that may cause problems electing a new cluster coordinator and primary node, because a quorum can't be reached.

It would be cleaner to **disconnect, offload and delete** those nodes first from the cluster GUI so that these references are deleted. Those nodes can then be configured as a fresh cluster with an empty flow. Even if you use the old flow again later, test it out with an empty flow to make it a lot quicker.

Since you already split the cluster, I would try to start one node of the 8 member cluster and see if you can access the cluster menu to delete the split-off nodes (disconnecting and offloading probably doesn't work anymore). Then for the other 7 members of the cluster, delete the flow.xml.gz and start them. They should copy over the flow from the running node. You should adjust the number of candidates expected in nifi.properties (nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates) so that is not larger than the number of nodes to slightly speed up this process.

If successful, you then have the 300 MB flow running on the 8 member cluster and an empty flow on the new 5 member cluster.
Connect the new cluster to your development pipeline (NiFi registry, templates or otherwise). Then you can stop process groups on the 8 member cluster, import them on the new and after verifying that the flows are running on the new cluster, delete the process group from the old, slowly shrinking it.

If you have no pipeline or it's too much work to recreate all the controllers and parameter contexts, you could take a copy of the flow.xml.gz to one new node, start only that node and delete all the stuff you don't need. Only after that should you start the others (with their empty flow.xml.gz) again.

For more expert advice, you should also try the Apache NiFi Users email list. If you supply enough relevant details in your question, someone there may know what is going wrong with your cluster.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. Finally both the Nifi clusters are up after 4 days.  We actually followed most of the points mentioned above. Only one step is not included that is to "disconnect, offload and delete".

Comment: @VinayAnnayya You're welcome. Please also accept the answer if you consider it to be the correct answer to your question, so that others can see it worked for you.